# setOnItemClickListener() not working on ExpandableHeightGridView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

Hello good morning in my view i cant handled the setOnItemClickListener

I am trying to create an application which dynamically lists installed applications in a gridview.I am able to display the applications in a gridview form but not able to make these items clickable. Nothing happens when i click these items. The code inside the setOnItemClickListener does not get triggered on click event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tab2profile">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
//my scrollview 
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/MainRLyout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/girislayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/usernameTv"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_Orta"
                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:ignore="PrivateResource" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Login_LogOut_Button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:minHeight="0dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/logout_rounded"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/logout_icon"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/Logout_Text_str"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap,RtlHardcoded" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                //in here i cant handled the item click funktşon
                <syr13.comapp4.Custum_Adapters.ExpandableHeightGridView
                    android:id="@+id/Your_Apps_Li"
                    android:numColumns="3"
                    android:layout_below="@id/Your_Apps_Tv"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </syr13.comapp4.Custum_Adapters.ExpandableHeightGridView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can Change your Code

from

> button.setOn**Item**ClickListener(this);

To

> button.setOnClickListener(this);

for example :-

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.button:
                    //Do Something
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```